# Django based video asset review system

Tags: python, django, pipeline

I've been asked to develop a video review system.

- it would need multiple levels of permissions e.g. internal review, client review.
- notes(comments) on all the submissions.
- revisions of the video assets.
- searching of video assets.

publishing these video assets will need to be done from the commandline. because it would be as a final step in a long chain of task being handed to our render-farm.

initially we don't need to video's to play in the browser directly just have a link to the source file and to a generated mov.

Is Django the right thing to use for something like this? is it difficult to create "content" revision control? how is django with commandline input? or is there something better to do this?

any thoughts would be appreciated.

Lars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django will do this just fine. There are a coulpe revision control apps out there, a quick google search turned up this: [Django-Revision](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) as far as command-line usage you can [write your own management commands](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: will Django-revision give the option of showing,search and list all the versions of a model? being completely new to django the lingo is still very confusing to me. the user will need to switch quickly between versions of the video asset.

Comment: It looks like, with the built in methods, you can pull up revisions by date or you can get a list of all the unique versions, which then would let you filter out the ones you don't want.